# No module named 'object_detection'

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I downloaded Tensorflow object_detection API. I was able to run the tutorial and see the results.

However, while I want to train my own data, i have an error here at this code:

```
python3 train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

The error will came out as below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "train.py", line 49, in
>   
>       from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'

Here the code snippet from train.py:

```
import functools 
import json
import os
import tensorflow as tf 

from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder
from object_detection.builders import graph_rewriter_builder
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
from object_detection.legacy import trainer
from object_detection.utils import config_util
```

**Info:**

I'm using Tensorflow 1.10 and Windows 10

**Note**

I run this code however it didn't work for me.

> set PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim

Comment: can you try ```pip freeze``` and check whether you could see ```object_detection``` or not ?

Comment: Did you import the object_detection api in top of code

Comment: after run pip freeze, its show object-detection==0.1

Comment: Post a code snippet. Also make sure you have imported all your files properly.

Comment: I import the object_detection and now the error only on train.py line 49,  from object_detection import trainer

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps.
Change to the object detection directory, activate your virtualenv and then do the following

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:home/<username>/<path>/models/research
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:home/<username>/<path>/models
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:home/<username>/<path>/research/slim
PATH=$PATH:$PYTHONPATH

cd .. (Make sure you are now in the research directory)
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Now change to the `object_detection` directory and try the `train.py` command again.
Hope this helps you out. Let me know in case you face any issues.